# Removed class files from android folder but still eclipse compiles and runs with no problems. how?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In order to see how eclipse works, I removed the textview.java file from the android.widget folder. yet i am still able to compile and run the app on my phone with the text showing. How is this possible?

The same is the case with the Bundle.java file.  I removed it from the android.os folder and wanted to see if there would be an error message in the mainactivity.java file code within eclipse but the statement `import android.os.Bundle;` did not have a red line under it and did not show an error message. I was able to compile and run the app on the phone. How is this possible?

By the way, I am removing the files from the folder corresponding to the API number of the target version of android.

thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not eclipse guy ( i use android studio ) , Is there any `compileSdkVersion` in eclipse project setting / gradle files?

Comment: The target SDK version is the one that will be compiled against, so he/she's on the right track.

Comment: yes. it is called the `Build Target Version` option which is set to API 15 and I removed files from the `android-15` folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have an android.jar in your libs folder -> which contains all the references you need.

the files themselves are ON THE DEVICE and not compiled with your project so deleting the contents of the API folder is not going to change it

the contents of the api folder is for you to be able to connect the android.jar with the source

see picture below
[image]

[image]

> > Platform version
>
> Different devices may run different versions of the Android platform,
>   such as Android 4.0 or Android 4.4. Each successive platform version
>   often adds new APIs not available in the previous version. To indicate
>   which set of APIs are available, each platform version specifies an
>   API level. For instance, Android 1.0 is API level 1 and Android 4.4 is
>   API level 19.
>
> The API level allows you to declare the minimum version with which
>   your app is compatible, using the  manifest tag and its
>   minSdkVersion attribute.
>
> For example, the Calendar Provider APIs were added in Android 4.0 (API
>   level 14). If your app cannot function without these APIs, you should
>   declare API level 14 as your app's minimum supported version like
>   this:
>
> ...
>
> The minSdkVersion attribute declares the minimum version with which
>   your app is compatible and the targetSdkVersion attribute declares the
>   highest version on which you've optimized your app.
>
> Each successive version of Android provides compatibility for apps
>   that were built using the APIs from previous platform versions, so
>   your app should always be compitible with future versions of Android
>   while using the documented Android APIs.
>
> Note: The targetSdkVersion attribute does not prevent your app from
>   being installed on platform versions that are higher than the
>   specified value, but it is important because it indicates to the
>   system whether your app should inherit behavior changes in newer
>   versions. If you don't update the targetSdkVersion to the latest
>   version, the system assumes that your app requires some
>   backward-compatibility behaviors when running on the latest version.
>   For example, among the behavior changes in Android 4.4, alarms created
>   with the AlarmManager APIs are now inexact by default so the system
>   can batch app alarms and preserve system power, but the system will
>   retain the previous API behavior for your app if your target API level
>   is lower than "19".
>
> However, if your app uses APIs added in a more recent platform
>   version, but does not require them for its primary functionality, you
>   should check the API level at runtime and gracefully degrade the
>   corresponding features when the API level is too low. In this case,
>   set the minSdkVersion to the lowest value possible for your app's
>   primary functionality, then compare the current system's version,
>   SDK_INT, to one the codename constants in Build.VERSION_CODES that
>   corresponds to the API level you want to check.

taken from : [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)
The code that you claimed to have "removed" is installed by default on your device.
and this is why your app continues to run.